# Button Target doesn't execute function in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I'am trying to execute something when a button on a tableview is pressed. I added the button to the cell in the storyboard and connected it like that:

```
@IBOutlet weak var likeMessage: UIButton!
```

Afterwards, I added a target and the tag on the button in the cellForRowAt.

```
  cell.likeMessage.tag = indexPath.row
  cell.likeMessage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SignalRViewController.handleLikes(sender:)), for:.touchUpInside)
```

And I have the handleLikes function in the same class(SignalRViewController).

```
func handleLikes(sender: UIButton){
        print("was clicked")
    }
```

I found this way on other posts, but 
I can't get it to work. What do I miss?

**Update**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        self.tableViewMessage.backgroundView = nil
            //My Messages
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myMessageCell", for: indexPath) as? MyMessageTableViewCell  else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of Community")
            }
            cell.imgUser.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imgUser.frame.height/2
            cell.imgUser.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.imgUser.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
            cell.lblMessage.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping // or NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
            cell.lblMessage.numberOfLines = 0
            cell.background.layer.cornerRadius = 7
            cell.lblMessage.text = "\(arrayMessage[indexPath.row][0])"
            cell.lblMessage.textAlignment = .left

            cell.imgUser.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:222/255.0, green:225/255.0, blue:227/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            cell.background.backgroundColor = constants.duckEggBlue
            cell.imgUser.downloadedFrom(link: userImageServer)
            cell.lblTimestamp.text = getFormattedTime(index: indexPath.row, cell: "myCell")
            cell.likeMessage.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.likeMessage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLikes(sender:)), for:.touchUpInside)

            return cell}
```

[image: Picture with the Storyboard]

Comment: Please write method handleLikes on UITableViewCell class.

Comment: Try using this since it is in the same class:
`cell.likeMessage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLikes(sender:)), for:.touchUpInside)`

Comment: @saroshmirza Didn't work as well

Comment: @Fabioha can you share the whole code snippet in

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: @saroshmirza I updated the post with the whole code snippet

Comment: @Fabioha, cool there are two more things to check
first can you try changing these two to the following

`func handleLikes(){
        print("was clicked")
    }`



`cell.likeMessage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLikes), for:.touchUpInside)`

if this also dosen't work the most probably the delegate is not set for the table view

Comment: @saroshmirza I doesn't change anything, i also checked if userinteraction is enabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151397/discussion-between-sarosh-mirza-and-fabio-ha).

Comment: @Krunal I added the screenshot

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why it doesn't work but personally when I need to put a button in a cell I use an @IBAction which trigger a delegate like :

```
import UIKit
protocol MySuperTableViewCellDelegate: class {
   func didPressCheckBoxButton(cell: MySuperTableViewCell)
}

class MySuperTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
     weak var delegate: MySuperTableViewCellDelegate?

     @IBOutlet weak var checkBoxButton: UIButton!

     @IBAction func checkBoxButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if let d = delegate {
           d.didPressCheckBoxButton(cell: self) 
        }
     }

    //Here is the default code like "awakeFromNib" etc
}
```

And in the viewcontroller where you show the tableview when you create the cell in "CellForRowAt Indexpath" I need to put 
"cell.delegate = self"
So your controller is delegate of each cell

and at the end of your viewcontroller :

```
extension MySuperViewController : MySuperTableViewCellDelegate {
  didPressCheckBoxButton(cell: MySuperTableViewCell) {
      print("checkbox button has been pressed")
  }
}
```

Comment: i really appreciate you way but my suggestion is Using blocks is better then protocol

Comment: Can you tell me why ? is it a better way to do for application efficiency or something like that ? If protocol aren't good I will start to use the other way but I learned to do like that

Comment: Not like that 
But, if something requires one function as it's interface, a callback (Clouser) is usually a good solution. If more than one function is required, especially when they're required for the basic function of an object, a Delegate is probably a better solution.